# One button used for two Action

Tags: android

Can any one tell me? how can i use the same button for two Action? 
Like em using one button in my activity that calculate some values and after calculating the when i  again press same button then reset the all fields. Like in this Application
http://www.craziness.com/games/play-love-tester/ when i test the love by pressing the button
then i again press the same button then all fields reset.
what should i use in my activity for the above problem?

Comment: maybe use a [toggle button](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a global variable which indicates the state of the program and then change this value when needed. In the `OnClickListener` of your `Button` you create an `if` statement which checks this variable and does the needed things for the associated value.

Example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int state = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (state == 0) {
                    // State 1
                }
                else if (state == 1) {
                    // State 2 
                }
                else {
                    // Default state
                }
            }
        });

        // Rest of your code including state changing part
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can do it by changing the button text.

If you do not want that someone sees the text change. Test (example "click" and the other state "click " (1 blank at the end) or another solution.

```
....

Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
//  todo: check for expected instance (Button) 
Button btc = (Button)v;
String bText = btc.getText().toString();

if (bText == "open") {
     btc.setText("close");
     }
     else if (bText == "close") {
     btc.setText("open"); 
     }
}

[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using a toggle button.

In your xml file add a toggle button

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/tbtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:textOff="Reset"
    android:textOn="Calculation"
    android:background="@drawable/icon"/>
```

Java file

```
public class Reviews extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ToggleButton tbtn;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    tbtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbtn);
    tbtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (tbtn.isChecked()) {

            //calculate the result
        } 
        else {

             //Reset your global calculation variable;
        }

        }
    }
}
```